# ECS Community Edition vs EMC ECS Software

Tags: emc

What are the major differences between the [ECS Free & Frictionless Community Edition](https://github.com/EMCECS/ECS-CommunityEdition) and the official [ECS Appliance Software](https://support.emc.com/products/37236_ECS-Appliance-Software) listed on EMC's support site?

Will the Free version track all the official version's releases?
To be more specific, is the "emcvipr/object" docker container the same for both the free version and the EMC Official release?
If so, will they be kept in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently came across the information in an EMC dev training session by the ECS community edition maintainers.  They have code releases sort of in sync with paid versions, and you can check for release info of the docker containers from docker hub [here.](http://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=emccorp&starCount=0)  Most major/minor releases and some patched versions will be available.

Answer (score 0):

The software releases are one and the same, however the license for the Community Edition is for non-production use only.

-Andrew

Comment: Please provide a source backing up your claims. As your answer stands it would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: I agree with the first commenter. @AndrewVieyra
[Docker Hub ECS Object link](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/emccorp/ecs-software/) shows a version as follows: "Release Version: ECS object 60101"
[EMC Support downloads](https://support.emc.com/downloads/37254_ECS-Appliance-) shows there is an ECS version 2.0 HF3.
Are these two versions the same?  It doesn't appear they are...

Comment: It looks like the ECS ver 2.0HF3 from emc support includes the ECS Object version 60500... So my question is still open.  How closely will the Docker Hub Version track the EMC released version?  How often will the Docker Hub version be updated to keep in sync with the EMC supported production releases.